# Difficulty with FindFit with complex equation

Tags: fitting

I want to fit the following equation for my experimental data. I used the following code but it does not give the answer.

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
   data, {Convolve[
     a*UnitStep[x - b]*c*Sqrt[x - b]*
       Divide[Pi*Divide[Sqrt[d], Sqrt[x - b]]*
         Exp[Pi*Divide[Sqrt[d], Sqrt[x - b]]], 
        Sinh[Pi*Divide[Sqrt[d], Sqrt[x - b]]]] + 
      a*d*Sum[Divide[4*Pi, n^3]*DiracDelta[x - b + d/n^2], {n, 1, 1}],
      VoigtDistribution, x, y], b < Min[data[[All, 1]]], 
    b < Min[data[[All, 1]]]}, {{a, 10}, {b, -1}, c, d}, x];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
```

Comment: You'll need to add a restriction for `b` such as `b < 1` (if you don't specify the `x` values) or `b < Min[x]` (if you do specify the `x` values in the dataset).  (I suspect the extra comma at the end of `FindFit` is a typo entered here.)

Comment: Thank you,FindFit[l1, 
 a*UnitStep[x - b]*c*Sqrt[x - b]*
  Divide[Pi*Divide[c, Sqrt[x - b]]*Exp[Pi*Divide[c, Sqrt[x - b]]], 
   Sinh[Pi*Divide[c, Sqrt[x - b]]]], x2, {a, b, c}],I corrected it.but out put is "Search specification 1.37777777777778` without variables should be a \
list with 1 to 4 elements"What does it mean.What is the wrong with this

Comment: You'll need to show at least a subset of what you have in `data` (or `l1` as you're calling now).

Comment: Thank you very much, What does it mean, Could you please provide an example code. It is a great help for me.

Comment: Your code works fine with made-up data in the expected format.  That suggests to me that there's something special about your data - either the values or the structure.  I don't think anyone can help until you show at least some of `data` or `l1`.

Comment: My data is like this.is it enough  you to get the idea?Is there any way to contact you?Then I can provide more.
{0.807292, 0.334473}, {0.80415, 0.333431}, {0.801034, 0.332193}, \
{0.797941, 0.331024}, {0.794872, 0.329786}, {0.791826, 0.328846}, \
{0.788804, 0.327797}, {0.785805, 0.326909}, {0.782828, 0.32591}, \
{0.779874, 0.324893}, {0.776942, 0.323883}, {0.774032, 0.322896}, \
{0.771144, 0.321917}, {0.768278, 0.320953}, {0.765432, 0.319928}, \
{0.762608, 0.318885}, {0.759804, 0.317574}, {0.757021, 0.316674}, \
{0.754258, 0.315271},

Comment: You've changed your question.  You say "it does not give an answer".  You give no error messages.  You give no data.  Do you see how it might be difficult for anyone to give specific help?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are feeding `FindFit` with just the response variable and the predictor variable is assumed to take on the values 1, 2, ....

If so, then your error message allows one to reconstruct some of the data:

```
y = {2.15658, 2.16407, 2.1716, 2.17916, 2.18675, 2.19437, 2.20203, 
  2.20973, 2.21746, 2.22523, 2.23304, 2.24088, 2.24876, 2.25668, 
  2.26464, 2.27264, 2.28068, 2.43294, 2.44186, 2.45084, 2.45986, 
  2.46894, 2.47808, 2.48727, 2.49652, 2.50583, 2.51519, 2.52462, 
  2.5341, 2.54365, 2.55326, 2.56293, 2.57266}

data = Transpose[{Join[Range[17], 34 + Range[16]], y}]
```

A plot of the data reveals a an uninteresting function:

```
ListPlot[data]
```

[image: Plot of data]

Your complicated function is much too complicated for the data.  Here is the fit using `NonlinearModelFit` and assuming `b < data[[All,1]]`:

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
   data, {a*UnitStep[x - b]*c*Sqrt[x - b]*
     Divide[Pi*Divide[c, Sqrt[x - b]]*Exp[Pi*Divide[c, Sqrt[x - b]]], 
      Sinh[Pi*Divide[c, Sqrt[x - b]]]], 
    b < Min[data[[All, 1]]]}, {{a, 10}, {b, -1}, c}, x];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 8.46225, b -> -113.529, c -> 0.0235281} *)
```

But these estimates are not to be trusted.  Not because of *Mathematica* doing something wrong but because the model is much too complicated for the available data.  This conclusion is supported by an examination of the correlations among the parameter estimates:

```
nlm["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1. & -0.999855 & -1. \\
 -0.999855 & 1. & 0.999855 \\
 -1. & 0.999855 & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The high correlations suggest that you really only have at most 2 parameters that can be estimated rather than 3.

I can't duplicate the error you're getting using my guess as to what is a subset of what your data looks like.  Maybe if you give the whole dataset, then one could track down the reason for the error message.  But in any event, your model is way too complicated for the data.

**Update**

With the sample data the same situation exists:  the proposed model is too complicated for the data.

```
data = {{0.807292, 0.334473}, {0.80415, 0.333431}, {0.801034, 
    0.332193}, {0.797941, 0.331024}, {0.794872, 0.329786}, {0.791826, 
    0.328846}, {0.788804, 0.327797}, {0.785805, 0.326909}, {0.782828, 
    0.32591}, {0.779874, 0.324893}, {0.776942, 0.323883}, {0.774032, 
    0.322896}, {0.771144, 0.321917}, {0.768278, 0.320953}, {0.765432, 
    0.319928}, {0.762608, 0.318885}, {0.759804, 0.317574}, {0.757021, 
    0.316674}, {0.754258, 0.315271}};

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
   data, {a*UnitStep[x - b]*c*Sqrt[x - b]*
     Divide[Pi*Divide[c, Sqrt[x - b]]*Exp[Pi*Divide[c, Sqrt[x - b]]], 
      Sinh[Pi*Divide[c, Sqrt[x - b]]]], 
    b < Min[data[[All, 1]]]}, {a, {b, -1}, c}, x, 
   MaxIterations -> 1000];
nlm["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 215.58, b -> 0.322036, c -> 0.00220429} *)
nlm["CorrelationMatrix"] // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1. & -0.999969 & -1. \\
 -0.999969 & 1. & 0.99997 \\
 -1. & 0.99997 & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

At this point I think just fitting a straight line is all that is warranted.  If the complicated model has some physical meaning and you know it to be correct, then the question to ask is "Why doesn't the data support that model?"

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: That works for me, Thank you very much. I want to convolve two equation, then I want to find the parameters. But it doesn't give the answer and Takes too much time. What is the wrong with my code?

Comment: I have entered my new code.