# Ranging the parameter in Fitting

Tags: fitting

I want to apply a range for parameters(a,b,c,d).What is the correct way to do it?

```
fit3 = NonlinearModelFit[
      data, {f4, b < Min[data[[All, 1]]]}, {{a, 10}, {b, -1}, c, d}, y]
```

Comment: What's data? What's the model `f4`? The only thing that I can say at the moment is that  the inequality constraint is at the correct place (should better be a `<=`), but the `{{a, 10}, {b, -1}, c, d}` looks fishy. What do you expect from that?

Comment: That exact restriction (except for the `f4,` was in an answer given to you in a recent question:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/182332/difficulty-with-findfit-with-complex-equation.  Did it not work?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I used `<` rather than `<=` because there was potential for division by zero and getting imaginary numbers if `b >= Min[data[[All,1]]]`.  (There was division by 'Sqrt[x - b]`.)

Comment: @JimB My concern was that optimization on open sets often have no minimum because "the minimizers lie on the boundary". But each good optimization algorithm would interpret `<` as `<=` anyways.